# Not Displaying Array List properly?

Tags: java

I only have one arrayList and I want the out put to print in table format I know with Arrays you would need to use a nested for loop one for the rows and the other for the columns, How would I be able to have my output be in a table format when using arrayList my for loop:

```
System.out.print("Inv/Mo.\tRate\tYears\tFuture Value\n");

     for (int i = 0; i < FutureValueArrayList.size(); i++)

      {

         String FutureValueArray = FutureValueArrayList.get(i);

         System.out.print(FutureValueArray + "\t");

      }
```

my for loop gives me an output like this:

> $100.00 2.0% 2 $2,450.64 **$150.00 2.0% 2 $36,420.71**

The bold values are a second entry by the user. How do I get it to display on the second line and for every new entry of values it outputs it line by line as opposed to everything in one line? I tried `print`/`println` and it still out puts everything in the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Use Guava library where is Joiner.on(" ").join(arraylist); it produces nicely formatted output, you can define even custom iterators or filters in guava.

https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained#Joiner

To format output better you can use stringObject.replace(x,y); which allows you to replace symbols by e.g. \n - new line or you can add more spaces ...

```
 String str = sentence.replace("and", " ");
```